# Shorter way to POST FORM in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, post

I am using angularjs php form post to insert or update row. Currently I have working example below and I want to know if this can be written in shorter way so that it can used in both UPDATE and INSERT scenario. I want to submit the whole FORM not just the defined value. Thanks for help.

```
function update($con){
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input", true);
$request = json_decode($postdata);

$idx = $request->idx;
$images = $request->images;
$collection = $request->collection;
$title = $request->title;
$description = $request->description;
$height = $request->height;
$width = $request->width;
$length = $request->length;
$weight = $request->weight;
$price = $request->price;
$availability = $request->availability;
$active = $request->active;
$method = $request->method;
$searchkeys = $request->searchkeys;
$materialused = $request->materialused;
if(is_array($images)){
    $implodeImg = implode(',', $images);
}else{
    $implodeImg = $images;
}

$sqlIn = "UPDATE prodList_1 SET 
idx = '$idx',
images = '$implodeImg',
collection = '$collection',
title = '$title',
description = '$description',
height = '$height',
width = '$width',
length = '$length',
weight = '$weight',
price = '$price',
availability = '$availability',
active = '$active',
method = '$method',
searchkeys = '$searchkeys',
materialused = '$materialused'
WHERE idx = '$idx'";

if (mysqli_query($con, $sqlIn)) {
  echo "Record Updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sqlIn . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `mysqli` and probably will never after doing this but I believe it would be something like the following:

```
function update($con) {
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input", true);
    $request = json_decode($postdata);

    $idx = $request->idx;
    $images = $request->images;
    $collection = $request->collection;
    $title = $request->title;
    $description = $request->description;
    $height = $request->height;
    $width = $request->width;
    $length = $request->length;
    $weight = $request->weight;
    $price = $request->price;
    $availability = $request->availability;
    $active = $request->active;
    $method = $request->method;
    $searchkeys = $request->searchkeys;
    $materialused = $request->materialused;

    if (is_array($images)) {
        $implodeImg = implode(',', $images);
    }else{
        $implodeImg = $images;
    }

    // using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax
    // make sure idx is PRIMARY KEY
    $sql = "
        INSERT INTO table 
        (idx, images, collection, title, description, height, 
         width, length, weight, price, availability, active, 
         method, searchkets, materialused) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        images = VALUES(images), collection = VALUES(collection), 
        title = VALUES(title), description = VALUES(description), 
        height = VALUES(height), width = VALUES(width), 
        length = VALUES(length), weight = VALUES(weight), 
        price = VALUES(price), availability = VALUES(availability), 
        active = VALUES(active), method = VALUES(method), 
        searchkeys = VALUES(searchkeys), materialused = VALUES(materialused)
    ";

    // never trust user-submitted data
    // use prepared statement
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);

    $stmt->bind_param(
        $stmt,
        'sssssssssssssss',
        $idx, $implodeImg, $collection, $title, $description, 
        $height, $width, $length, $weight, $price, $availability, $active,
        $method, $searchkeys, $materialused
    );

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)) {
        echo "Record Updated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sqlIn . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
```

So.. in terms of your question whether this can be written in a shorter way? Not really. However, you can kill two birds with one stone using [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Thanks Mikey, I felt the same when I realize that I have to do this but what are the options if I am on shared hosting with just mysql php admin database. I will try to implement you suggestion and see how it goes.

Comment: Check if [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is installed on your shared hosting. I would believe most hosting providers would have that by now as it is widely used. PDO has a lot more features and, personally, seems much more easier to use.

Comment: Thanks Mikey, I'll check that out

Comment: I was looking in PDO but its looks very simlar to mysqli. Both INSERT and UPDATE needs to define fields and value same way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is SQL Injectable, you will want to look up how to prevent SQL Injection through parameterization and other methods. However, you can use the `$request` as an array and a foreach loop to do this. Perhaps something like this:

```
$request = [
    "idx" = "idx",
    "images" => "implodeImg",
    "collection" => "collection",
    "title" => "title",
    "description" => "description",
    "height" => "height",
    "width" => "width",
    "length" => "length",
    "weight" => "weight",
    "price" => "price",
    "availability" => "availability",
    "active" => "active",
    "method" => "method",
    "searchkeys" => "searchkeys",
    "materialused" => "materialused"
];
$sql = "UPDATE prodList_1 SET";

$last_key = end(array_keys($request)); // Grab the last key and remove comma if present in $sql
foreach($request as $k => $v) {
    if($last_key !== $k) {
        $sql .= "$k = $$v, ";
    } else {
        $sql .= "$k = $$v ";
    }
}
$sql .= "WHERE idx = '$idx'";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sqlIn)) {
  echo "Record Updated successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sqlIn . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

You can `echo $sql;` to check to see if your parameter is being parsed correctly.

Comment: Thanks Allen, I'll try and see how it goes.